# SSRS parameters, populating the available fields list

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008, reporting-services, bids

When producing a list of available parameter properties, rather than manually typing each persons name in one by one, is there any way of just populating the data from the table/view which holds all the possible names?

I assume its in the circled box however all that does it let me point to a dataset and then field which I have tried selecting `StaffName` (being the field that is the one I'm using) if I then run the report it falls over.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS's concept of a query is largely tied to a data set that you define in Report Data.

When you choose 'Use a query', you should be choosing a pre-defined query from Report Data.  Of course, the good news is that you can define these yourself.

So let's take your example.  You want your possible parameter options to be StaffNames.

Create a new dataset in Report Data.  It should return all possible staff names for your report.

```
Something like:-

SELECT DISTINCT 
  StaffName,
  StaffID
FROM
  MyReportViewOrTable
```

Once you have defined this dataset, you should be able to use it as a source of parameter values.

Answer (score 3):

Add a new dataset to the report, maybe called `StaffMembersDS`. The SQL for it might look like:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM StaffMember;
```

Then assign `Name` to Label and `Id` to Value.

BTW if this is related to your last question you're going to run into the trouble that when a user picks a staff member name from the drop down list they are picking only **one** value. So for your case you might want the Value field to be tied to `Name` as well as the label. That would allow you to use the query in your last question - [SSRS Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432399/ssrs-parameters) - which collects related `Id` values.